# Finding binary matrix from spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, binary

Consider an unknown symmetric matrix $A$ consisting of zeroes and ones. We know

- The eigenvalues of $A$.
- Every row in $A$ has the same number of ones, which implies that one eigenvector of $A$ is $v=(1,1,\dots, 1)^T$.

Can we find $A$ (up to permutations, perhaps) efficiently?

Comment: I've deleted the post I had. I'll see if I can find a solution. I have a question: if the eigenvalues are 4, 3, -5, then 4 is the dominant eigenvalue? Not -5?

Comment: Actually, I think that assumption can be simplified to just say it is the vector of ones. I think it will always be the dominant one (absolutely and not absolutely), but perhaps that's irrelevant.

Comment: So then the third and second pieces of information are equivalent?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'll edit to point that out, but I'll leave it all, as it might be informative.

Comment: I think a solution to this might imply the answer to a major open question in combinatorics, so an efficient algorithm is perhaps unlikely to exist. I'll try to elaborate and turn it into an answer if I get anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=[1,\cdots,1]^T$. Since $A$ is a non-negative matrix and also a symmetric matrix, there is a permutation $P$ s.t. $B=PAP^{-1}=diag(B_i)_{i\leq k}$ where the $B_i$ are irreducible or $0$ and, moreover, are symmetric.

Notice that $Pu=u$ and $Au=\lambda u$, where $\lambda$ is a positive integer; then $Bu=\lambda u$ and, moreover, $B_iu=\lambda u$ and all the $(B_i)$ are irreducible.

$\rho(B_i)=\lambda$ is the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue of $B_i$. Since $B_i$ is symmetric, the only possible eigenvalues with maximal modulus  are $\pm \lambda$. Let $h_i$ be the period of $B_i$. If $-\lambda\in spectrum(B_i)$, then $h_i=2$ and $\pm\lambda$ are simple eigenvalues of $B_i$; else, $B_i$ is aperiodic and primitive (there is $m_i$ s.t. ${B_i}^{m_i}>0$).

When $h_i=2$, there is a permutation $Q$ s.t. $QB_iQ^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}0_r&C\\C^T&0_r\end{pmatrix}$. Then $\chi_{B_i}=\det(\lambda^2I-CC^T)$ divides the known polynomial $\chi_A$ and has opposite real roots ($\pm$ the singular values of $C$); in particular, the dimension of $B_i$ is even.

Remark. The multiplicity of $\lambda$ in $spectrum(A)$ is equal to $k$. The multiplicity ($\leq k$) of $-\lambda$ in $spectrum(A)$ is equal to the number of $B_i$ s.t. $h_i=2$.

Toy example. $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix},B_1=[1],h_1=1,B_2=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},h_2=2$.

EDIT. We consider the OP's example: $\chi_A=(x-4)(x^2-2)^3$.

Here, $\lambda=4$ and there is only one block $B_1$ of dimension $7$  which is primitive. Notice that my post above reduces the problem to submatrices of $B$, only when $k>1$; thus my study is useless for this example.

Yet, we can solve it, using the Grobner basis method. We consider an algebraic system in the $28$ unknowns $(a_{i,j})_{i\leq j}$.

i) The simplest relations are $Au-u=0$ and ${a_{i,j}}^2-a_{i,j}=0$.

ii) Since $trace(A)=4$, we may assume (up to a permutation) that $a_{1,1}=a_{2,2}=a_{3,3}=a_{4,4}=1,a_{5,5}=a_{6,6}=a_{7,7}=0$.

iii) We add the relations $trace(A^2)=28,trace(A^3)=64,trace(A^4)=280$. In particular, we do not use the values of $trace(A^5),trace(A^6),trace(A^7)$.

We obtain the Grobner basis in 1"7 and the previous relations are enough for all solutions to have $\chi_A$ as characteristic polynomial. There are $24$ solutions; to obtain a particular solution, one arbitrarily imposes

$a_{1,2}=a_{1,3}=a_{2,5}=a_{1,6}-1=0$. Finally, a particular solution is

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&1&1&1&0\\0&1&0&1&0&1&1\\0&0&1&1&1&0&1\\1&1&1&1&0&0&0\\1&0&1&0&0&1&1\\1&1&0&0&1&0&1\\0&1&1&0&1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$.

We can see that $A^2>0$.

Comment: How about the spectrum $4$ with multiplicity 1, $\sqrt 2$ with multiplicity 3, $-\sqrt 2$ with multiplicity 3.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble to write the example in such detail. I'll analyze it later when I have the time and accept when I understand it.

Comment: This is very nice. One objection would be that this is not really efficient, as the computation of the Groebner basis can be expensive, right? Is it also expensive to determine whether a system arising from a particular spectrum has a solution? I think it must be.

Comment: i) Of course, the Grobner basis  method is convenient only for small values of $n$. Anyway, I think that it is a NP problem. Yet, there are many relations between the $(a_{i,j})$ and, consequently, when there exist some solutions,these relations are algebraically dependent. Thus, we do not have to use the most complicated relations.  ii) On the other hand, the possible characteristic polynomials are in finite number; in particular, a random polynomial is not suitable in general; then the Grobner method works much faster. For example, $\chi_A=(x-4)(x^2-3)^3$ is not associated to some solution.